# Justunfollow app font name

Tags: font-face, truetype

Does anyone know which font is used in the **Justunfollow** iOS app?

I'm especially interested in the font used for displaying numbers (not sure if it's the same one used for text in the app).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's asking to identify a font and isn't really a programming question.

Answer (score 1):

maybe take a screenshot and upload it to 'WhatTheFont'?

http://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/